# Grouping of android push notifications not working

Tags: android

I would like to stack the coming push notifications but they don’t group. I will have a lot of notifications and they should be  grouped together. Here is my code (I updated the code as @ishmaelMakitla suggested):

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.replaceExtras(extras);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (GROUP_ID != null) {

        Log.i("Game", "Game GROUP ID " + "---- " + GROUP_ID);

        int notId = GROUP_ID.equals(GROUP_ADDS) ? NOTIFICATION_ADD_ID : NOTIFICATION_GAME_ID;

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        if (isFirstTime == true) {

            Notification firstNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                    .setContentText(messageValue)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.take_4_free_logo_01)
                    .setGroup(GROUP_ID)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SOCIAL)
                    .setGroupSummary(true)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(messageValue))
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify(notId, firstNotification);

            Log.i("Game", "Notification ID First time " + "---- " + notId);

            isFirstTime = false;

        } else {

            Notification followUpNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
                    .setContentText(messageValue)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SOCIAL)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.take_4_free_logo_01)
                    .setGroup(GROUP_ID)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify(notId, followUpNotification);

            Log.i("Game", "Notification ID Following " + "---- " + notId);
        }

        // notify activity
        Intent intentNewPush = new Intent(Consts.NEW_PUSH_EVENT);
        intentNewPush.replaceExtras(extras);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intentNewPush);
    }
```

Comment: Are you testing in android < 5.0 ?

Comment: Nope. Android 5.0.1, API 21

Comment: You should set `.setGroupSummary(true)` for the first notification and this becomes the group summary for a group of notifications (belonging to group `GROUP_ID` in your case). Otherwise, each notification with `.setGroupSummary(true)` is treated as separate, new notification which is not what you want.

Comment: I have same issue, what I find out that if I do not setGroup, the notifications will be grouped automatically. All I want to separate "ongoing" notification from other notifications from my app. So "ongoing" notification woun't be collapsed inside group. So I do not setGroup for all notifications except for "ongoing".

Answer (score 0):

You should set .setGroupSummary(true) **ONLY** for the first notification and this becomes the group summary for a group of notifications (belonging to group GROUP_ID in your case). Otherwise, each notification with `.setGroupSummary(true)` is treated as separate, new notification. Here is a code (extend yours) that you can quickly run and let me know if it works as expected.

```
Notification followUpNotification= new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("Follow Up ")
         .setContentText("Follow Up Message")
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.free_logo_01)
         .setGroup(GROUP_ID)
         .build();

notificationManager.notify((notId+1), followUpNotification);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and suggestion but it's not working again. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I will update my code with yours added.

Comment: OK, please do so and let me know - by the way, are you getting the two notifications not stacked - maybe put a log statement to indicate when `isFirstTime` is `true` and when it is `false`. Also instead of passing `build.build()`, could you perhaps have `Notification yourNotification = ...(.build())` and then pass the `yourNotification` object to the `notify` method.

Comment: Yes, I checked. I receive all the notifications and they are shown but are not stacked. And the logic with isFirstTime and so on is working. And I again updated the code.

Comment: Which API Level are you working with here? Android 4.4 or higher?

Comment: Android 5.0.1, API 21

Comment: Have you tried switching to from `NotificationCompat` to `NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`? This is the only thing I can think of now, please give it a try so we can exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: I meant from `NotificationManagerCompat` to `NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`

Comment: Noted. I should probably try and reproduce this myself. But from the related threads that I have read - the only thing I can suspect now is perhaps you need a different notification style (could you try InboxStyle?) - the example is something like this: `.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()..setBigContentTitle("There are more notifications...")` you can [see example here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html). Let me know if this also has no effect.

Comment: No, there is no difference. There is something else happening.

Comment: OK, what's happening now?

Comment: I meant that maybe the problem is not with the following code but something else.

Comment: Possibly, will try and make time to reproduce this on my side - but do let us know if you get it right.

Comment: Of course I will but right now It's defiantly not working.

Comment: did you succeeded in reproducing the problem?